# r : Why is findAssocs() not working?

Tags: r, data-mining, correlation, text-mining, text-analysis

findAssocs() is not working, as is seen below.  "Lucid" and "dreaming" occur together quite often in the book.

```
> docs <- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
> freq <- colSums(as.matrix(dtm))
> ord <- order(freq)
> freq[tail(ord)]
one experi   will   can lucid dream
287   312   363   452   1018   2413
> freq[head(ord)]
abbey abdomin   abdu abraham absent   abus
1       1       1       1       1       1
> findAssocs(dtm, "dream", corlimit=0.6)
$dream
numeric(0)
> findAssocs(dtm, "dream", corlimit=0.1)
$dream
numeric(0)
> findAssocs(dtm, "lucid", corlimit=0.1)
$lucid
numeric(0)
> findAssocs(dtm, "lucid", corlimit=0.6)
$lucid
numeric(0)
>
```

The corpus is a single document, the text version of a book.  Does this function require at least two documents?  If so, if I split the book in half will I get the correlations regarding the book as a whole, or in regards to how the two halves compare to each other?

Answer (score 1):

It counts the number of documents, ignoring duplicate occurences.

Split e.g. into sentences or paragraphs.